# Node.js Mongoose: Value does not represent the set data, yet database has changed

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

When I call findOneAndUpdate and set `shared.warningMessage` to '', I can see the database has got the change, but when I logout `console.log(saved.shared.warningMessage);` the changes have not been reflected.

So do I need to call the database again to get the set value? Or is there some way of getting the set value back at the same time as setting it?

```
      const saved = await userModel
        .findOneAndUpdate(
          { 'email.confirmationCode': confirmationCode },
          {
            $set: { 'shared.warningMessage': '', 'email.confirmed': true },
            $unset: { 'email.confirmationCode': '' },
          }
        )
        .exec();
      if (!saved) throw new Error('Invalid confirmation code');
      console.log(saved.shared.warningMessage);
```

I dont want to remove the key and value for `shared.warningMessage` I just want it to have no value hence ''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the `new` property in your options to tell mongoose to return the document **after** the update was done:

```
  const saved = await userModel
        .findOneAndUpdate(
          { 'email.confirmationCode': confirmationCode },
          {
            $set: { 'shared.warningMessage': '', 'email.confirmed': true },
            $unset: { 'email.confirmationCode': '' },
          },
          {
            new: true // this will return the doc after the update was done
          }
        )
        .exec();
      if (!saved) throw new Error('Invalid confirmation code');
      console.log(saved.shared.warningMessage);
```

[Docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/findoneandupdate.html)

As per docs:

> new: bool - if true, return the modified document rather than the
>   original. defaults to false (changed in 4.0)